# How do I print all sub attributes in comma separated format in one line

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to get only attribute name in one horizontal line.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 

data = '''
<job_details>
    <role>
        <name>Vikas</name>
        <salary>$5.95</salary>
        <job_description>Developer</job_description>
    </role>
    <role>
        <name>Dip</name>
        <salary>$7.95</salary>
        <job_description>Backend Developer</job_description>
    </role>
</job_details>
'''

xml_parsing = ET.fromstring(data)
for sub_attrib in xml_parsing[0]:
  print(sub_attrib.tag)
```

Expected output:

```
name,salary,job_description
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create array then `.join()`

```
xml_parsing = ET.fromstring(data)
attributes = ",".join(x.tag for x in  xml_parsing[0])
print(attributes)
# name,salary,job_description
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `bs4`.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')

out = soup.text.strip().split('\n\n\n')

for a in out:
    print(a.replace('\n',','))
```

OUTPUT:

```py
Vikas,$5.95,Developer
Dip,$7.95,Backend Developer
```